# A Token was not found in the TokenStorage

Tags: symfony

So I'm authenticating users using Guard Authenticators.

Login and logout was successful, but when I tried to request on other route, it throws AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException saying

> A Token was not found in the TokenStorage.

Thus, responding with 401.

This is my authenticator class:

```
class ApiAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
    {
        public function getCredentials(Request $request)
        {
            if ($request->getPathInfo() != '/login' || !$request->isMethod('POST')) {
                return;
            }

            $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

            return [
                'username' => $data['_username'],
                'password' => $data['_password'],
            ];
        }

        public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
        {
            return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials);
        }

        public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
        {
            if (!$user instanceof User) {
                throw new \TypeError();
            }

            return true;
        }

        public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
        {
            return new JsonResponse([ 'error' => 'Invalid Credentials!'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);    }

        public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
        {
            $response = [
                'success' => 'Success!',
                'customer' => [
                    'name' => 'Fullname',
                    'memberSince' => 'mm/dd/yyyy'

                ]
            ];

            return new JsonResponse($response, Response::HTTP_OK);
        }

        public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
        {   
            return new Response('', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        public function supportsRememberMe()
        {

        }

        public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
        {
            $request->getSession()->invalidate();
            return new Response();
        }
    }
```

This is my UserProvider class:

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $apiHelper;
    private $session;

    public function __construct(ApiHelper $apiHelper, Session $session)
    {
        $this->apiHelper = $apiHelper;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($credentials)
    {
        $response = $this->apiHelper->generateAccessToken($credentials['username'], $credentials['password']);

        if (isset($response['access_token'])) {

            $this->session->set('authAccessToken', $response['access_token']);
            $this->session->set('authExpiresIn', $response['expires_in']);
            $this->session->set('authRefreshToken', $response['refresh_token']);

            $accessToken = new AccessToken();
            $accessToken->setAccessToken($response['access_token']);
            $accessToken->setExpiresIn($response['expires_in']);
            $accessToken->setTokenType($response['token_type']);
            $accessToken->setScope($response['scope']);
            $accessToken->setRefreshToken($response['refresh_token']);

            return new User($accessToken);
         }

         throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', '')
        );
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user))
            );
        }

        return $user;

            // return $this->loadUserByUsername([
            //     'password' => $user->getPassword(),
            //     'username' => $user->getUsername(),
            // ]);
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return User::class === $class;
    }
}
```

and this is my security.yml

```
security:
    providers:
        user_provider:
            id: user_provider

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            http_basic: ~
            pattern: ^/
            provider: user_provider
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                success_handler: api_authenticator
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - api_authenticator
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/test, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, I just return the $user in refresshUser() and it works.
I'm not really sure whiy :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
main:
    # ...
    anonymous: true
    # ...
```

to **security.yml** will help to turn that exception to *AccessDeniedException* (which should usually turn to *InsufficientAuthenticationException* in dev mode and redirect to login using a kernel exception listener in prod mode, but it's up to you).

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement `AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface` and throw an exception in `onAuthenticationFailure`.